# How to clear a text field from another text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below which represents two text fields. I need a method to only allow the user to type in information in ONE text field and block the other text field.

```
<fieldset>
        <h3><?php _e('City', 'bender'); ?></h3>
        <div class="row">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" id="sCity" name="sCity" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_city()); ?>" />                             
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h3><?php _e('Region', 'bender'); ?></h3>
        <div class="row">               
            <input class="input-text" type="text" id="sRegion" name="sRegion" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_region()); ?>" />
            <script>
             $("#Sregion").val('');
            </script
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

So for example, if the textfield `City = "London"`, the postcode becomes blank/clear

if textfield `region = "Cambridgeshire"`, city becomes blank/clear.

How can I do this? I suspect this can be done in either Jquery/javascript? But I can't find a solution to my problem.

Also, currently if the user types in a City, the Region automatically gets added, and I also need to block that. So, ideally, as soon as its onFocus(), it needs to be blanked/greyed out.

Thanks!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7ek11cfs/1/)

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link ?

Comment: try use on "input" event `$("input").on("input", function(){//some logic})`

Comment: what is `<script>$("#Sregion").val('');</script` Is it required if yes then close it properly as `</script` must be `<script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear value of other text box on the `focus` or `keyup` of first one so that if user enter city name then populated region name also get empty, see below jquery :

```
  $( "#sCity" ).on("focus keyup",function() {
      $("#sRegion").val("");
    });

   $( "#sRegion" ).on("focus keyup",function() {
      $("#sCity").val("");
   });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/7ek11cfs/10/)**

Comment: did you find any success?

Answer (score 2):

I understand you need to disable the other text field when one gets focused. Using JQuery u need to have code like this. # is to represent selector for id

```
$( "#city" ).focus(function() {
    $("#region").prop('disabled', true);
});

$( "#region" ).focus(function() {
    $("#city").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

this prop disable is supported jQuery version 1.6+ 
Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried it on fiddle and it doesn't seem to work? Have I implemented correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/7ek11cfs/11/

Comment: You need to add jquery lib from left drop down box ..http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/7ek11cfs/12/

Comment: @Khaleel, on focus of one element you are disabling another but then you cannot focus on disabled text again and it will be lock.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar thanks for reply. Slight problem is that when the user deletes it the box remains disabled. How do I enable it again?

Comment: @gudthing please check this fiddle -updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khaleel/7tyrmc73/5/ . I have the fix for your query. Note that I have changed the wrapping div's class to add handlers. add comments if u want more explanation. This is working perfectly fine